# How to use TCP send out a HTTP response?

Tags: http, browser, tcp

I try to use c++ develop a HTTP server on Windows,and when i reponse a HTTP by use `WSASend` to send out

`char response[] = 
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\n\r\
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\n\r\
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT\n\r\
Content-Length: 88\n\r\
Content-Type: text/html\n\r\
Connection: Closed\n\r\n\r\
<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>"`

Althrougn the browser did show `Hello, World!` when i type in `127.0.0.1`,but the browser just keep show loading sigh as if the pages not yet load complete.And the browser's console never show the response message.Why?

Is there some format issue with my response message?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Content-Length: 88\n\r\
> ....
> Connection: Closed\n\r\n\r\
> ```

There are several problems with your code. All over your code you use `\n\r` instead of `\r\n`. Therefore the response is invalid HTTP. And the `Content-length` header must reflect the actual length of the body: `<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>` has 48 bytes and not 88 bytes as your code claims. Apart from that it must be `Connection: Close` instead of `Connection: Closed`.

Note that HTTP is way more complex than you think. If you really need to implement it yourself instead of using established libraries please study the actual standard (that's what standards are for!) instead of fiddling around until it seems to work. Otherwise it might work only within your specific environment and with a specific browser and you'll get strange problems later.